# Plot topics with bokeh or matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, bokeh

I'm trying to plot topic visualization from a model.
I want to do something like bokeh covariance [implementation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/les_mis.html).

My data is:

```
data 1: index,                            topics.   
data 2: index, topics, weights(use it for color).
```

where topic is just set of words.

How do i give the data to bokeh to plot the above data? From the example, data handling is not intuitive.

With matplot, it looks like [this](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2ymubgi&s=8#.UzWe43WrDQY).
Obviously, it is not visually helpful to see what topic correspond to each circle.
Here is my matplotlib code:

```
x = []
y = []
area = []

for row in joined:
      x.append(row['index']) 
      y.append(row['index'])
      #weight.append(row['score'])
      area.append(np.pi * (15 * row['score'])**2)
scale_values = 1000
plt.scatter(x, y, s=scale_values*np.array(area), alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Any idea/suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**UPDATE**: The answer below is still correct in all major points, but the API has changed slightly to be more explicit as of Bokeh 0.7. In general, things like:

```
rect(...)
```

should be replaced with

```
p = figure(...)
p.rect(...)
```

---

Here are the relevant lines from the Les Mis examples, simplified to your case. Let's take a look:

```
# A "ColumnDataSource" is like a dict, it maps names to columns of data.
# These names are not special we can call the columns whatever we like.
source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        x = [row['name'] for row in joined],
        y = [row['name'] for row in joined],
        color = list_of_colors_one_for_each_row, 
    )
)

# We need a list of the categorical coordinates
names = list(set(row['name'] for row in joined))

# rect takes center coords (x,y) and width and height. We will draw 
# one rectangle for each row.
rect('x', 'y',        # use the 'x' and 'y' fields from the data source
     0.9, 0.9,        # use 0.9 for both width and height of each rectangle 
     color = 'color', # use the 'color' field to set the color
     source = source, # use the data source we created above
     x_range = names, # sequence of categorical coords for x-axis
     y_range = names, # sequence of categorical coords for y-axis
)
```

A few notes:

- For numeric data `x_range` and `y_range` usually get supplied automatically. We have to give them explicitly here because we are using categorial coordinates.
- You can order the list of names for `x_range` and `y_range` however you like, this is the order they are displayed on the plot axis.
- I'm assuming you want to use categorical coordinates. :) This is what the Les Mes example does. See the bottom of this answer if you want numerical coordinates.

Also, the Les Mis example was a little more complicated (it had a hover tool) which is why we created a ColumnDataSource by hand. If you just need a simple plot you can probably skip creating a data source yourself, and just pass the data in to `rect` directly:

```
names = list(set(row['name'] for row in joined))

rect(names,    # x (categorical) coordinate for each rectangle
     names,    # y (categorical) coordinate for each rectangle
     0.9, 0.9, # use 0.9 for both width and height of each rectangle
     color = some_colors, # color for each rect
     x_range = names, # sequence of categorical coords for x-axis
     y_range = names, # sequence of categorical coords for y-axis
)
```

Another note: this only plots rectangles on the diagonal, where the x- and y-coordinates are the same. That seems to be what you want from your description. But just for completeness, it's possible to plot rectangles that have different x- and y-coordinates. The Les Mis example does this.

Finally, maybe you don't actually want categorical axes? If you just want to use the numeric index of the coordinates, its even simpler:

```
inds = [row['index'] for row in joined]

rect(inds,    # x-coordinate for each rectangle
     inds,    # y-coordinate for each rectangle
     0.9, 0.9, # use 0.9 for both width and height of each rectangle
     color = some_colors, # color for each rect
)
```

**Edit**: Here is a complete runnable example that uses numeric coords:

```
from bokeh.plotting import * 

output_file("foo.html")

inds = [2, 5, 6, 8, 9]
colors = ["red", "orange", "blue", "green", "#4488aa"]

rect(inds, inds, 1.0, 1.0, color=colors)

show()
```

and here is one that uses the same values as categorical coords:

```
from bokeh.plotting import * 

output_file("foo.html")

inds = [str(x) for x in [2, 5, 6, 8, 9]]
colors = ["red", "orange", "blue", "green", "#4488aa"]

rect(inds, inds, 1.0, 1.0, color=colors, x_range=inds, y_range=inds)

show()
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the color only when co-ordinates are same and rest grey. But its not working even though the color array is ok.http://pastebin.com/jKQGJDRr

Comment: Hi @sb32134, I noted a couple of bugs in your code that prevented Bokeh from rendering exactly what you wanted.

Your `color` list was generated properly, but there's a distinction between the `inds` indices you were building and the categories you wanted to appear on the plot.

I've put up an IPython Notebook which will hopefully clarify the issue: https://www.wakari.io/sharing/bundle/kpsfire/Categorical

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks to both @kpsfire and bigreddot. Your replies really motivated me in last few days.I also realized it is one thing to get beautiful visualization but importantly a visualization that gives insight about the data is real visualization. I now find bokeh really useful. I'll be exploring more now with bokeh.